# Is there a semantic tag or attribute (with value) for legend (outside table or form)?

Tags: html, semantic-markup

Although I have asked myself this question for different cases that work outside a table (where you can use caption etc.), here is an example:
I have a page with bar graphics with different colors which are the main content and above that I have some content (for now with tag `<aside>`) that describes all colors, just as a "legend".

So, what is the best choice here for semantics?
If there are many choices and "best" is ambiguous, let's say for Search Engine "data relevance".

Further thinking out loud:
The `<legend>` tag is supposed to be for forms, that's a pitty.
A role attribute ? But so many possibilities though still I don't really find the right one.

Comment: A heading works pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your example correctly, you shouldn’t use `aside`. The color legend is important for understanding the content, not just "[tangentially related](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-aside-element)".

HTML5 doesn’t provide a way to denote that some content is a *legend* (and nothing else!) for some other content.

If you think your content is appropriate for `figure`, you can use the [`figcaption` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/grouping-content.html#the-figcaption-element) for the legend.

If you think your content is appropriate for `table`, you can use the [`caption` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/tabular-data.html#the-caption-element) for the legend.

Else, use a sectioning element (or `body` for a stand-alone document) with a [`header` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/CR-html5-20130806/sections.html#the-header-element), which "typically contains a group of introductory or navigational aids". *Introductory* seems to come close.

```
<article><!-- or section -->
  <h1><!-- heading for your bar graphics --></h1>
  <div><!-- bar graphics --></div>
  <header><!-- color legend --></header>
</article>
```

If the color legend is complex, and if it should appear in the document outline, it might be appropriate to give it its own `section` inside of the main content’s sectioning element.

```
<article><!-- or section -->
  <h1><!-- heading for your bar graphics --></h1>
  <div><!-- bar graphics --></div>
  <header>
   <section>
     <h1>Color legend</h1>
     <!-- color legend -->
   </section>
  </header>
</article>
```

All three ways are appropriate for marking up a legend; but they don’t express that it’s *definitely* a legend. `figcaption`, `caption`, and `header` can be used for other things, too.

Comment: Sounds better and thought of that too, but isn't there really a way to tell the header is a legend or "something explanatory" for the rest? I mean they made <caption>, <legend> and even the below <figcaption> for less important content, but not for main content?  Really? Isn't this discussed somewhere?

Comment: @R-U-Bn: `caption` is for tables, `legend` for forms, `figcaption` for figures … and why not `header` for sections? The `header` applies to the "nearest ancestor sectioning content", so it’s semantically expressed thas this content serves as "metadata" (so to say) for the content in that section. I don’t think that it’s necessary to have an specific element only for legends; `legend`/`figcaption` aren’t especially for legends, either.

Comment: I am not saying ´header´ is no good, not at all. I am just wondering if there isn't anything more specific, possibly even inside or as attribute of that header.
Anyway, are you "telling" there isn't a semantic way to put more specificity towards legend, in stead of just header? If so, please say so in your post and I will accept it, preferably with an endorsing or authoritative link.

Comment: @R-U-Bn: I edited my answer (however, nothing to link to state that something doesn’t exist).

Comment: Thanks.  In stead of a link to state that something does not exist, have you come across any discussion like this or neighbouring this question?  From discussion groups or similar and not from quotations you made (which are appreciated nonetheless)!

Answer (score 3):

`<figcaption>` might be the element for you.

According to the HTML5 specification:

> [The figcaption element represents a caption or legend for a figure](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/figcaption.html)

To be used as follows:

```
<figure>
    <figcaption>
        <dl>
            <dt class="yellow">Yellow</dt>
            <dd>Whatever yellow represents</dd>
        </dl>
    </figcaption>
    <img alt="Totally semantic representation of a bar chart" src="/chart.svg" />
</figure>
```

I took the liberty of chucking in a definition list for your individual legends because they're jam packed full of fun semantic implications.

Comment: I am not sure about this, because a figure is semantically not important or from your own link "can be moved away from the main flow of the document without affecting the document’s meaning".

Comment: What so you mean when you say a 'figure is semantically not important'? My last use case for `<figure>`s was using them as wrappers for figures in scientific papers. They were incredibly semantically important — so much so that the `<figcaption>` element exists specifically to enhance them. They can be moved out of the main flow, as we did, because documents that make reference to figures will often choose to link to them separately. What are your semantic concerns, exactly? What elements do you think would be more 'semantically important' that you would otherwise be using for your figures?

Comment: Maybe I described it a bit ambiguous. I mean that a figure is meant as  something that is not main content, but illustrates the main content. Hence my quotation.  And in my case my bars áre the main content of my page. So, I am really wondering if this is the best solution.

Comment: Figure and figcaption seems to be the best construct to mark up a chart and its legend. You may misunderstand the docs a bit, "without affecting the document's meaning" means that you can reference the figure on its own as it doesn't need any other content to be interpreted correctly. It says nothing really about the importance of the element itself. I think you could see it like an article tag which makes sense on its own, e.g. "consists of a self-contained composition in a document... ...that is intended to be independently distributable" but may be it's most important part.